# How do I provide user-to-user payments in my app?

Tags: javascript, ios, paypal, stripe-payments, braintree

Is there a payment gateway that allows 1 user (UserA) to send a payment directly to another user (UserB) after both have successfully provided their normal credit card details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is fairly broad so can't answer any specifics here.

If you are doing this with Stripe, you need to implement Stripe Connect for both users.

Each user would have a Connect account and a Customer object associated with them.

I'd recommend going over Stripe Connect [0] and the fund flows [1] thoroughly as there is a lot of detail/options here.

And would recommend checking with Stripe Support if your use-case is permitted under their terms of service.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/connect

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges

Answer (score 1):

For a user to pay another user's email, [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) has a `payee` field:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/custom-payee/

I believe the receiver doesn't even have to have a PayPal account set up yet (they receive an email and can click to set up and accept, or add the email to an existing PayPal account.  If not accepted gets auto refunded in 30 days)